# Laravel project acting different on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have just uploaded my project to shared hosting. It works fine on my localhost server. Is there a difference with the way session data is stored on shared hosting?

```
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $item= Listings::where('id',$id)->first();

        if($item->id === $user_id){
    }
else
{
                abort(404);
}
```

It keeps throwing a 404 error ?

Answer (score 0):

did you move your public file to your root folder on your share hosting ?

because you need to be careful about this section. and usually as i experienced before, it's just about your boostrap location and public file location.